# How do sites track the amount of time their users spend on referred pages?

Tags: javascript

How does some sites achieve the ability to track the amount of time a users spend on a referred page?

One example is a site I've seen that provides a list of offers, where each site will pay you for spending a designated amount of seconds on their homepage, then you click that offer, you are transferred to their homepage in a new window with a timer showing how many seconds you have been there for, at the end of the time period you can go back to the first page and now your account has been updated with a payment.

How is this possible, and which frameworks are needed to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Probably custom JavaScript code using `setInterval` and update state every few seconds
2. Save the state in `Cookie` or `LocalStorage`